# How to access data from HDF5 with hierarchical keys?

Tags: python, pandas, hdf5

I have created a store in HDF5 with hierarchical keys with the following structure

```
<class 'pandas.io.pytables.HDFStore'>
File path: path-analysis/data/store.h5
/attribution/attr_000000            frame        (shape->[1,5])
/attribution/attr_000001            frame        (shape->[1,5])
/attribution/attr_000002            frame        (shape->[1,5])
/attribution/attr_000003            frame        (shape->[1,5])
.....
/impression/imp_000000              frame        (shape->[1,5])
/impression/imp_000001              frame        (shape->[1,5])
/impression/imp_000002              frame        (shape->[1,5])
/impression/imp_000003              frame        (shape->[1,5])
.....
```

From what I have read in the documentation I should be able to access impression and attribution in the following manner

```
store.select('impression')
store.select('attribution')
```

However, I get an error:
    TypeError: cannot create a storer if the object is not existing nor a value are passed

To add the data to the store, I have iterated over my data frames

```
store.put('impression/imp_' + name, df)
```

Originally, I used append api to create a single table 'impression', however that was taking 80sec per dataframe and given that I have almost 200 of files to be processed, the 'append' appeared to be too slow.

In comparison, 'put' is taking less than a sec to add to the store however it does not let me select data later.

How should I access my data given the structure above?

Also, why is append so much slower than put? Can it be sped up?

Subsequently, I want to be able to group impression data by a certain column and same for attribution data. 
So I need to be able to select column also.

Am I taking a wrong approach here for structuring my data?

Here is df info

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 251756 entries, 0 to 257114
Data columns (total 5 columns):
pmessage_type       251756 non-null object
channel             251756 non-null object
source_timestamp    251756 non-null object
winning_price       251756 non-null int64
ipaddress           251756 non-null object
dtypes: int64(1), object(4)None
```

here is the sample of the data

,pmessage_type,channel,source_timestamp,winning_price,ipaddress
    0,impression,online,1400792099000,1800,99.34.198.9
    1,impression,online,1401587896000,200,99.60.68.61
    2,impression,online,1400873220000,735,65.96.72.183
    3,impression,online,1400768556000,5550,73.182.225.30
    4,impression,online,1401255378000,2099,65.96.72.183
    5,impression,online,1400992770000,88,73.182.225.30
    6,impression,online,1400709948000,290,162.228.58.98
    7,impression,online,1400634607000,1720,162.228.58.98
    8,impression,online,1399201568000,710,108.206.240.138

This data is exported by using df.to_csv(...) for simplicity.

How the original data gets loaded into data frame is with the following snippet.

```
data = pd.read_csv(events_csv_file,
                   delimiter='\x01',
                   header=None,
                   names=my_columns.keys(),
                   dtype=my_columns,
                   usecols=my_subset_columns,
                   iterator=True,
                   chunksize=1e6)
df = pd.concat(data)
```

where

my columns is a dictionary:

```
{'attribution_strategy': object,
 'channel': object,
'flight_uid': object,
'ipaddress': object,
'pixel_id': object,
'pmessage_type': object,
'source_timestamp': object,
'source_unique_id': object,
'unique_id': object,
'user_id': object,
'winning_price': numpy.int64}
```

The intention behind specifying types manually is to gain speed. (I have read somewhere that help the processing, though I did not observe such improvements)

Also, my pandas version if that makes any difference

```
>>> pandas.__version__
'0.14.0'
>>>
```

=====================

Here is an example that can be easily reproduced

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo',
                     'bar', 'bar', 'bar', 'bar',
                     'foo', 'foo', 'foo'],
               'B': ['one', 'one', 'one', 'two',
                     'one', 'one', 'one', 'two',
                     'two', 'two', 'one'],
               'C': ['dull', 'dull', 'shiny', 'dull',
                     'dull', 'shiny', 'shiny', 'dull',
                     'shiny', 'shiny', 'shiny'],
               'D': np.random.randn(11),
               'E': np.random.randn(11),
               'F': np.random.randn(11)})

store = pd.HDFStore('mystore.h5')
store.put('data/01', df)
store.put('data/02', df)

print store

<class 'pandas.io.pytables.HDFStore'>
File path: mystore.h5
/data/01            frame        (shape->[11,6])
/data/02            frame        (shape->[11,6])
```

And this is what I am trying to get at

```
store.select('data')
```

However I get an error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-33-60360d11cde5> in <module>()
----> 1 store.select('data')

/Users/sshegheva/anaconda/envs/numba/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/pytables.pyc in select(self, key, where, start, stop, columns, iterator, chunksize, auto_close, **kwargs)
    650         # create the storer and axes
    651         where = _ensure_term(where, scope_level=1)
--> 652         s = self._create_storer(group)
    653         s.infer_axes()
    654 

/Users/sshegheva/anaconda/envs/numba/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/pytables.pyc in _create_storer(self, group, format, value, append, **kwargs)
   1157                 else:
   1158                     raise TypeError(
-> 1159                         "cannot create a storer if the object is not existing "
   1160                         "nor a value are passed")
   1161             else:

TypeError: cannot create a storer if the object is not existing nor a value are passed
```

In contrast, removing data by selecting top key in hierarchy does work as expected

```
store.remove('data')
```

Comment: Your exact question is here in the docs: http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/io.html#hierarchical-keys. If you want to have more help with actually storing your data, show ``df.info()``. And a sample of what you are querying

Comment: @Jeff, yes I have looked at the doc and that is exactly where I found the example of 'put', except that select does not work as expected. Updating the question with more data...

Comment: @Jeff, updated the question with more information. Apologies if questions are too simple. I am new to both HDF5 and stackoverflow. Thanks for help

Comment: how are you reading the data in the first place? you need to non-object dtypes for non-string data (strings are object dtype).

Comment: @Jeff, my example started to look complex. I will try to mock my scenario using a simple dataset which can be easily reproduced

Comment: try only specifying the dtype for columns which actually really need it (like the IP address).